# SQLite multiple queries in parallel

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database file, and I realize when attempting to write or read from it, it opens and locks the db file.  Is there any way to avoid the lock so a second script can access it as well?

In other words, how do I perform a NOLOCK on a SQLite3 database file?

Answer (score 2):

That is not how [SQLite's locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) works. Multiple connections can read from the DB at the same time. And with [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), readers are not blocked by a writer.